# form onsubmit submit the other form

Tags: forms, onsubmit

how can I submit the form2 automatically when I submit the form1?

```
if( $_POST['submit'] == 'Submit')
{ im going to put my form2 here then automatically submit.
what code do i need?}

<form name=form1 action=# method=post>
<input type=submt name=submit value=Submit />
</form>
```

NOTE my form2 have different action that's why I cant include the content of my form2 to my form1

It can also be, when I click something, those two form will be submitted.

Comment: You can always change your form's action (and just about everything else) using JavaScript **before** you submit a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple function would do that (if I've got your question right :-S)

```
function submitForm()
{
  document.form2.submit();
}
```

Call this function from the submit

```
<input type="submit" onclick="submitForm();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Link the onsubmit event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) of each form to a new function "launchMyForms". 
In these function launch your forms manually:

```
$('#myform1').submit();
$('#myform2').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has Ajax functions that serialize and submit forms